# Joomla access permission error

Tags: joomla

When i'm going to edit content in Article, i got below error.

```
Forbidden

You don't have permission to access /administrator/index.php on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.
```

i can't edit my content. how could i avoid this ?

Comment: Can you log into the administration area? If so, is the Article Manager the only component that throws this error?

Answer (score 3):

Sometimes when editing articles, the content of the article is flagged by the server as dangerous (e.g. code in the article looks like an attempt at SQL injection), which results in the HTTP 403 you received. You can try editing your content to make it less suspicious, or you will need to look at the security layer in play on your server.

If your server uses Mod Security, you will probably need to contact your hosting company to add a rule exception. If you use some sort of Joomla security add-on, then it's possible that that is the piece responsible for throwing the 403.

If you aren't sure, your best bet might be to ask your hosting company or sysadmin.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. I couldn't solve it, but a quick workaround would be to edit the article directly in the database, under jos_content (replace jos_ by your table prefix if different). When you are editing the article in Joomla's backend, look in the URL for the ID of this article. Then, in the table, search for that ID (ex : `SELECT * FROM jos_content WHERE id = YOUR_ID`). Edit the content field, and there you go

Answer (score 0):

If you are using Mac, change the permission of the Joomla folder to "read&write".