# Joomla Custom component with Mod_security

Tags: joomla, joomla1.5, mod-security

I had built a custom component for Joomla v 1.5.23.However now when my forms in the backend send any HTML content I get the following error

**Forbidden
You don't have permission to access /administrator/index.php on this server.
Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request.**

However when I submit the form without the html content it updates and I am redirected to my component page.

I am using the following configuration

PHP built on : Linux bluemoon19.ukhost4u.com 2.6.32-13-pve #1 SMP Mon Jul 9 08:39:20 CEST 2012 x86_64

PHP version: 5.3.14

Joomla : Joomla! 1.5.23 Stable [ senu takaa ama baji ] 04-March-2011 18:00 GMT

Any ideas ?

Comment: Last I checked this was an issue caused because of Mod_security

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9768733/joomla-access-permission-error